# CSS Gurus please help me figure these rounded corners out?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rounded-corners

I've got a webpage I'm designing and my design works great in google's Chrome browser but I'm using the CSS 'border-radius' property which as I'm sure you know isn't supported by IE.  I'm trying everything I can think of but I've got a few things going on that are causing me a lot of trouble

- The 'box' in question that I'm trying to get rounded corners on has a white background with a background image
- The page background is a gradient and the outside corners must be transparent to look right.
- I've got a green border running around my box.

Here's a sample image that shows what I'm trying to achieve:
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/77c9ec6c32.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/77c9ec6c32.png)

Let me know if it would help to see my current CSS and HTML.  I've tried a lot of different things but they all have one problem or another.  The box background is set in my CSS as a non-repeating image set in the lower right and the fading effect comes from it being partially transparent so it fades to white since that's the background color of the box.  A fluid solution would be nice but I can use a fixed-width solution just fine.

The background is what's causing my main problem.  I can't figure out how to make the background fill the whole thing if I break up the HTML into more than one div.

HTML:
    `<div class="content">`
      `<jdoc:include type="component" />`
    `</div>`

CSS:
    .content {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border: solid 2px #ACD579;
      -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
      -moz-border-radius: 13px;
      border-radius: 13px;
      padding: 1em 2em;
    }
    .content
    {
      background-image: url(../img/pagebG.gif);
      background-position: bottom;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }

Comment: Yes. It would help very much to see your current code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310833/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-standards-based-cross-browser-compatible-rounded

Comment: I've added my current code that works in everything I've tried but IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you provide your code, so we can see where you're going wrong.
Also, is the page breaking in IE6? or just IE in general? 
To get rounded corners in IE you could use [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/), which makes "Internet Explorer 6-8 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features.".

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I'm trying to make CSS3 Pie work right now.

Comment: Thanks so much this was the best solution I found by a large margin!