# html5.js not working in ie 7 and 8 for me

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

You can view my site here - http://patiss-themes.com/planetary/ and as you can see on chrome and other browsers, also IE 9, it has transparent background (for content) and rounded corners, but on IE7 and IE8 after including html5.js (you can view in page source), it doesn't change anything, could someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you be more specific: how exactly does the page break in IE7 and IE8?

Comment: Hello,It doesn't break, it just doesn't display the transparency and rounded corners for the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`html5.js`](http://remysharp.com/html5-enabling-script) will only enable styling of the new elements, such as `<article>`, `<section>`, ...

It will *not* enable CSS3 effects which weren't implemented in those browsers.

Comment: Hello, Oh thanks! how can I easily activate rounded corners and opacity?

Comment: @Pienskabe: for adding rounded corners, checkout the answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310833/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-standards-based-cross-browser-compatible-rounded

Comment: @Pienskabe: You could use conditional comments and `filter: alpha(opacity= <value>)` for opacity (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity#Cross_Browser_compatible_Live_Example).